# Can I / should I download html5 code within a cordova app?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, html, cordova

Lets say I had a HTML5/JS based application that is wrapped in cordova phone gap. Can I have it startup and download additional html5/js files? Basically the app would work with the base files, but additional features or changes can be provided and downloaded instead of installing a new version of the application.

The use case for this would be an app for a business which may want to have their own extensions.

Is this a possibility? Would this cause the app to be denied in the apple app store? What are your thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: Apple don't permit downloading of JS except unless if that is done from within the context of a web view. I think cordova runs everything within a web view foundation?

Comment: It does, and that's odd. Why would apple allow code-on-demand only in the context of webviews and not allow it otherwise?

Comment: Something to do with security and it being sandboxed when done from a web view.

Comment: This is the apple documentation: "3.3.2 An Application may not download or install executable code. Interpreted code may only be used in an Application if all scripts, code and interpreters are packaged in the Application and not downloaded. The only exception to the foregoing is scripts and code downloaded and run by Apple's builtin WebKit framework, provided that such scripts and code do not change the primary purpose of the Application by providing features or functionality that are inconsistent with the intended and advertised purpose of the Application as submitted to the App Store."

Comment: @MartinH This really stands out:  "provided that such scripts and code do not change the primary purpose of the Application by providing features or functionality that are inconsistent with the intended and advertised purpose of the Application as submitted to the App Store." 

Potentially, we could just be displaying additional data. Same app, just maybe a new read only field. That sounds like it would still be consistent with the intended purpose. However, I also think that it would be rejected by the store because it _COULD_ extend it in a way that is inconsistent

Comment: There's no way of knowing until you actually submit the app. And if it gets rejected you can appeal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from comments:
"3.3.2 An Application may not download or install executable code. Interpreted code may only be used in an Application if all scripts, code and interpreters are packaged in the Application and not downloaded. The only exception to the foregoing is scripts and code downloaded and run by Apple's builtin WebKit framework, **provided that such scripts and code do not change the primary purpose of the Application by providing features or functionality that are inconsistent with the intended and advertised purpose of the Application as submitted to the App Store**." – Potassium Permanganate Sep 18 '15 at 16:33

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically it is a violation of the rules of the Markets. But in practice, many loaded some modules through the frames.

Comment: It update application bypassing Market controll system/

Comment: "3.3.2 An Application may not download or install executable code. Interpreted code may only be used in an Application if all scripts, code and interpreters are packaged in the Application and not downloaded. The only exception to the foregoing is scripts and code downloaded and run by Apple's builtin WebKit framework, provided that such scripts and code do not change the primary purpose of the Application by providing features or functionality that are inconsistent with the intended and advertised purpose of the Application as submitted to the App Store."

Comment: It is not known how  "customers" want to "upgrade" app.

Comment: It's not a violation anymore, as @MartinH pointed, you should update your answer as it's accepted and it's wrong